# Windows 10 Boot time is so slow

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just finished building my first PC and installed windows on its SSD. The first boot after setup is okay and the experience is what I expected from an SSD.

That's until i restarted my PC, the windows loading is going circular without lag at first second and will lag its animation after. That will go on for solid 15 mins until it boot up. After I got into the desktop, everything works fine.

I tried reinstalling windows and restart without installijg anything even drivers. and still did not solve the problem.

specs:
ryzen 5 3500x
Aorus b450m
16gb klevv ram
256gb ssd lexar
500gb hdd
gtx 1650

Answer (score 0):

15 minutes is way too long for a computer to reboot. If this is all brand new hardware, then you need to do some testing to ensure all the components are working correctly. Since you built the PC, you won't have the benefit of a PC manufacturer diagnostics program, and are left to what Windows, your hardware manufacturers, or free software are able to offer. Windows Event Viewer is probably going to be throwing errors if you have hardware issues.

When you first install Windows 10, it goes through a lot of configuration tasks, as well as updates. Even if you don't install updates, it still does some configuration on the first reboot and may pause the logoff and login cycle.

Whenever you setup a new custom built PC, the first thing you need to do is install the Windows updates and updated hardware drivers from your motherboard and CPU manufacturer. Then your GPU and the rest of your peripherals. The entire update process for Windows and all devices should take less than a couple hours.

After you've done all of this, and before you install any other programs, you are still having an issue, come back and update the post with hardware troubleshooting logs and screenshots.